# In Whitehead and Russell's PM, does not identity imply existance?

Tags: logic, math-history

At the end of ✳96.48, $ \sim(w=\overset{\smile}{R}‘max_R‘J_R‘x)$ is chosen over $ w\neq\overset{\smile}{R}‘max_R‘J_R‘x$, on account of the latter's implication of existence. But ✳13.02 states that they are the same.

> ✳13.02    $ x\neq y .=.\sim(x=y) $ Df

I wonder what I have missed. Where does PM say identity has anything to do with existence? Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Mauro. Same "sets of consequences" is exactly what I wanted to say but didn't figure out how to put it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a sleepless week I've decide to ask to Prof.Gregory Landini (Iowa University), my preferred "interpreter" of Russell's logic.

Here is his kind answer; I'll give it *verbatim* :

> This is a nice passage that illustrates something I've been arguing for years -- viz., definintions formed with individual variables cannot be applied to definite descriptions (because definite descriptions are not genuine terms). I didn't know it and find is wholly enjoyable that you found it and brought it to my attention.
>
> According to ✳30.01 $R‘y = (\iota x)(xRy)$ Df; thus, in our formula, "$\overset{\smile}{R}‘ ...$" is a definite description of a class and not a class term. Thus there is an issue of scope of the description.
>
> In order to apply the definition ✳13.02 [i.e. $x≠y.=.∼(x=y)$ Df] one must first eliminate the definite description. Note as well that when scope marker are dropped, smallest (most secondary scope possible) is intended.
>
> The general form of the case at hand is this:
>
> > $w \ne \iota aFa =_{df} [\iota aFa]( w \ne \iota aFa)$.
>
> This is the smallest scope possible -- because definition ✳13.02 is framed with individual variables and thus cannot apply until after the definite description has been eliminated.

In contrast,

> > $\lnot(w = \iota aFa) =_{df} \lnot [\iota aFa](w = \iota aFa)$
>
> The two scopes are not equivalent.

*Added*

This is explained by the "paradigmatic" case regarding "the King of France" and the management of scope in definite descriptions.

See *Principia* page 70 :

> $\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad [(\iota x) (\phi x)]. \lnot \psi(\iota x)(\phi x)$
>
> will mean $\quad \quad (\exists c): \phi x . \equiv_x. x = c: \lnot \psi c$,
>
> while $\quad \quad \lnot \{ [(\iota x) (\phi x)]. \psi(\iota x)(\phi x) \}$
>
> will mean $\quad \quad \lnot \{ (\exists c): \phi x . \equiv_x. x = c: \psi c \}$.
>
> Here again, when $(\iota x) (\phi x)$ does not exist, the first is false and the second true.

Thus, in ✳96.48, $\lnot(w=\overset{\smile}{R}‘ ...)$ corresponds to the second case, in which $\overset{\smile}{R}‘...$ does not exists.

Comment: Absolutely insightful! By *30.01, $\overset{\smile}{R}‘max_R‘J_R‘x$ is an incomplete symbol, therefore not an individual. Yes, there is an issue of scope. It is discussed in the summary of *14. So many thoughts are racing through my head now. I need to study some more. Thanks you so much, @Mauro, for your help. And please pass my thanks to Prof. Gregory Landini also.

Comment: @GeorgeChen - I've made some addition. You are right : it's not easy to find a fault into W&R's *Principia* ...

Comment: Thanks, @Mauro, for bringing my attention back to the King's chapter, every line of which is now full of meanings. Yes, that is where the ultimate answer is.

Answer (score 2):

W&R's comment above is not clear to me.

According to logical rules, an abbreviation is only a "symbol": it cannot alter the theorems provable in the system.

Thus, if $x \ne y$ is (as usual) an abbreviation for $\lnot (x=y)$, we have no possibility of having different "sets of consequences".

I think that the comment is related to ✳13.19 : $\vdash ∃y(y=x)$, which is a correct logic rule, and to the "missing" semantics of *PM*.

In "modern" first-order logic, the law : $\vdash ∃y(y=x)$ is (universally) *valid* because we assume that every *universe of discourse* (i.e.every domain of interpretation) is **not** empty. Thus, in every interpretation, we have at least one object, which is for sure "equal to itself".

The above law is usually derived from the *identity axiom* : $x=x$ through the $\exists$-introduction rule :

> from $\varphi(t)$, infer $\exists x \varphi(x)$.

If we apply the rule to $y \ne x$ (which is exactly : $\lnot (y=x)$), we can infer $∃y (y \ne x)$, but now we do not obtain a logical law.

The formula $∃y (y \ne x)$ is **not** (universally) *valid* because it is false in every domain with at least two objects, exactly like $y \ne x$.

I think that in ✳96.48 the free variable $w$ into $\sim(w=\overset{\smile}{R}‘max_R‘J_R‘x)$ must be read as implicitly universally quantified.

If so, the sub-formula is equivalent to $∀w \sim(w=\overset{\smile}{R}‘max_R‘J_R‘x)$ i.e.to $\sim \exists w (w=\overset{\smile}{R}‘max_R‘J_R‘x)$.

A possible reading of the annotation can be this: W&R want to avoid the misconception related to the above rule.

If we apply it to the formula $w\neq\overset{\smile}{R}‘max_R‘J_R‘x$ we can infer $\exists w (w\neq\overset{\smile}{R}‘max_R‘J_R‘x)$, which is **not** $\sim \exists w (w=\overset{\smile}{R}‘max_R‘J_R‘x)$.

Comment: Thanks, @Mauro. Give me a few more days. It seems that I can never spend enough time on introduction and part one.

Comment: I messed up the tail and the circle in the last comment.I agree that ∃y(y≠x) can't be taken for granted. w always exists. $\overset{⌣}{R}‘max_R‘J_R‘x$ exists only if $\overset{←}{R}_✳‘x$(the posterity of x with respect to R) is shaped like a Q. If $\overset{←}{R}_✳‘x$  consists of only $I_R‘x$(the circle) or only $J_R‘x$(the tail), then there is no junction to speak of and $\overset{⌣}{R}‘max_R‘J_R‘x$ does not exist. Still I agree with you that an abbreviation makes no difference in consequences.

Comment: A possible workaround is to interpret $w=\overset{\smile}{R}‘max_R‘J_R‘x$ in terms of *30.3, i.e. $w$ is **the** one that has relation $\overset{\smile}{R}$ to $max_R‘J_R‘x$. Also, PM 1st ed is not free from harmless mechanical errors, as is shown by *93.132 which was corrected in 2nd ed, but I'm very reluctant to admit faults in PM.